# Default HTML Buttons not visible with IE8

Tags: custom-fields, ie8, browser

I have a client who informs me that the Default HTML Buttons are not appearing with the field. I am using a mac with Safari and Firefox and they display no problem.
Anyone else encountered this problem?

Comment: Hi Kippi, welcome. Can you please edit your question to elaborate a bit more. What do you mean the "default HTML buttons"? Is this on your site's front end or control panel? Have you ever seen this problem yourself or are you going purely from client reports?

Comment: A few qns to help clarify: Is this a native RTE field? Is it only on a single field or all fields? Did you try logging in as that user to check if they accidentally removed their formatting buttons? (see http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/my_account/index.html#html-formatting-buttons)

Comment: by default html buttons I'm going to guess that means these http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/admin/default_html_buttons.html

Answer (score 5):

I haven't had this specific problem, but as a troubleshooting step, I'd see if the client is using the exact same CP URL that you are using - www vs not and admin.php vs system.

Answer (score 3):

From the information you have provided, I can only give you the general steps that you would need to take to resolve such an issue with Ellislab.

Since this would likely be a bug, you would need to post a bug report to the bug tracker.

http://expressionengine.com/bug_tracker/

However, you may want to confirm this through Ellislab's official support channel before posting a bug report.

If you can't wait, then you can also modify the control panel theme. Make a copy of the problem theme first, and then modify the copy.

http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/development/cp_styles/index.html